# Scrapy response incomplete

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I tried to crawl the following URL using Scrapy:
http://www.walgreens.com/search/results.jsp?Ntt=bounty+paper+towel

but the returned URL is not complete. Because when I do

```
scrapy shell the_url_above
```

then

```
view(response)
```

The webpage just doesn't load completely.  So my question is:

1. what is the cause of this problem? (why I didn't get a 404 but a incomplete response)
2. what are some potential ways to handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data for that page seems to be loaded in with javascript. If you inspect the page (e.g. firebug network tab) you'll see that once the base page is loaded the products are being loaded in by javascript which sends a POST request to `http://www.walgreens.com/svc/products/search` with contents:

```
{"p":"1",  # seems to be page number
"s":"15",  # page size
"sort":"relevance",
"view":"allView",
"geoTargetEnabled":false,
"q":"bounty paper towel",  # search query
"requestType":"search",
"deviceType":"desktop"}
```

You can just send this request using scrapy as:

```
yield Request('http://www.walgreens.com/svc/products/search',
              method='POST',
              body=<the json from above>)
```

And you should receive a json object full of product data.

You can actually even view the response in the browser via this link:
http://www.walgreens.com/svc/products/search?p=1&s=15&sort=relevance&view=allView&geoTargetEnabled=false&q=bounty%20paper%20towel&requestType=search&deviceType=desktop